# python ,return's position and filesize

Tags: python, return

Functions return the position of master well in python.

```
def myPath():
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(dir):
        for fn in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, fn)
            return path
        return path
    return path
```

```
ls /home/bb/C/
a.out  main.c  simple_write  t.c
```

## Three positions "return" is not what I want.

I want to get result "All the files in the C"

```
def filesize(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PATH):
        for fn in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, fn)
            size = os.stat(path).st_size
            yield size,path

for size,path in filesize(PATH):
        print size,path
```

but，How to achieve the above functions with the following code? How to modify it?

```
def find(path):
    return [os.path.join(root,fn)
        for root,dir,files in os.walk(dirs)
        for fn in files]
```

Answer (score 5):

Return a *list* of the paths, not only a single path:

```
def find(path):
    return [os.path.join(root, fn)
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path)
            for fn in files]
```

You could also use `yield` inside the inner loop to get a generator function, see [The Python yield keyword explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
def myPath(mydir):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(mydir):
        for fn in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, fn)
            yield path # <----- Instead of return


for path in myPath(some_dir):
    print path
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 ways if you need just the /home/bb/C directory listed

```
import os, glob

def listWithoutDirectories(path):
    return [os.path.join(root,fn)
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(mydir)
            if(root==path)
                for fn in files]

def listWithDirectories(path)
    return [os.path.join(path,fn)
        for fn in os.listdir(path)]


print listWithoutDirectories('/home/bb/C')
print listWithDirectories('/home/bb/C')
#Or with a glob
print glob.glob('/home/bb/C/*')
```